# Optimizing an `IN(x,y,z)` query on a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with several million rows.  It has over a dozen columns, many of which are long.  It is a large table.

I have a lot of common operations where I need to select data from 2 columns based on one of the columns as a lookup.

I have several indexes tuned to a handful of operations ; including ones that only contain an ID and some boolean fields.  This has largely worked out well.

I just ran into a problem, where an "IN()" select on a field that contains the md5 sum of another field became a bottleneck; deferring to a sequential scan and ignoring all indexes that had the md5 sum in it.

A normal scan took 45seconds.  Turning enable_seqscan off took a few milliseconds.

After playing around for a bit, I realized that this index would work:

```
CREATE INDEX speed_idx_YAY ON table( field_md5 );
```

But having any other fields in the index would fail:

```
CREATE INDEX speed_idx_BOO ON table( field_md5 , field_other );
```

The shift from using a multi-column index to a sequential scan happened "overnight", as the database grew.  At one time it worked, and then it didn't.

Does anyone have tips on how to best prepare for potential situations like this ?  Part of me is tempted to create single-column indexes for every indexed field on some tables as a backup.

Referenced:

- [Why doesn't Postgresql use index for IN query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181074/why-doesnt-postgresql-use-index-for-in-query/21181183#21181183)
- [PostgreSQL: Why is this query not using my index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275897/postgresql-why-is-this-query-not-using-my-index?rq=1)
- [Why isn't Postgres using the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187865/why-isnt-postgres-using-the-index?rq=1)

Comment: Please include your Postgres version, the table structure, and the full queries you are executing along with the explain plan for them.

Comment: Old explains are gone. Postgres on dev is 9.2.4; production is 9.3.2.  An example query would be `SELECT id, md5_field FROM table WHERE md5_field IN (1,2,4,5,6)`; but the table has 20+ fields. There were indexes on `id,md5_field`, and `id,md5_field,field_a,field_b,field_c` and a few other combos. From what I remember, on DEV it ran a "Seq Scan" filtering against the IN, and  removed 800k+ rows with that filter, returning 4.  Forcing the index scan, or with the single-column index, it performed an index scan. Just a 2-line explain on both: Index/Seq and Filter. Nothing nested.

Comment: Sounds like your `random_page_cost` and `effective_cache_size` doesn't accurately reflect the system's real performance.

Comment: Do you know the postgresql mailing lists? You can read them quite well on news.gmane.org. Database performance depends on so many factors which must be discussed, and you will find more of the performance specialists there than here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creatign indexes based on md5_field and include the other fields

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_speed_idx
ON speed_idx (md5_field)
INCLUDE (field_a,field_b,field_c);
```

Comment: That statement is invalid for Postgres (there is no `nonclustered` option and also no `include` option)